# Faster way to get mean of columns

Tags: python, pandas, performance

Input:

```
Home   Away   Home_goals Away_goals 
------------------------------------
Team 1 Team 2 2          1          
Team 3 Team 4 3          5
Team 2 Team 1 5          3
Team 4 Team 3 1          5
```

Output:

```
Home   Away   Home_goals Away_goals Mean
------------------------------------------------------
Team 1 Team 2 2          1          5.5 ((2+1+5+3)/2) 
Team 3 Team 4 3          5          7 ((3+5+1+5)/2)
Team 2 Team 1 5          3          5.5 ((2+1+5+3)/2) 
Team 4 Team 3 1          5          7 ((3+5+1+5)/2)
```

I need to get mean of total goals from H2H matches. This code should work but unfortunately this take a really long time to procedure. Is there a faster way how to do it?

```
def fce(team):
    team_1 = team.iloc[0]
    team_2 = team.iloc[1]

    new = df[(df["home"] == team_1) & (df["away"] == team_2) | (df["home"] == team_2) & (df["away"] == team_1)]
    mean = (new["home_goals"] + new["away_goals"]).mean()
    return mean

df["mean"] = df[["home", "away"]].apply(fce, axis=1)
```

Thanks

Comment: kindly share input data, with expected output. sample data, not pics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sorting `Home` and `Away` columns by rows, create `DataFrame`, add summed goal columns and use `mean` in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column:

```
a = np.sort(df[["Home", "Away"]], axis=1)
df['Mean'] = (pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index)
                .assign(sum = df[['Home_goals','Away_goals']].sum(axis=1))
                .groupby([0,1])['sum']
                .transform('mean'))
print (df)
     Home    Away  Home_goals  Away_goals  Mean
0  Team 1  Team 2           2           1   5.5
1  Team 3  Team 4           3           5   7.0
2  Team 2  Team 1           5           3   5.5
3  Team 4  Team 3           1           5   7.0
```

Alternative with assign new columns by array:

```
a = np.sort(df[["Home", "Away"]], axis=1)
df['Mean'] = (df.assign(t1 = a[:, 0],
                        t2 = a[:, 1],
                        sum = df[['Home_goals','Away_goals']].sum(axis=1))
                .groupby(['t1','t2'])['sum']
                .transform('mean'))
print (df)
     Home    Away  Home_goals  Away_goals  Mean
0  Team 1  Team 2           2           1   5.5
1  Team 3  Team 4           3           5   7.0
2  Team 2  Team 1           5           3   5.5
3  Team 4  Team 3           1           5   7.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I also tried to use just mean() instead of transform.('mean') and it works as well. One thing what I cant figure out, how does the sort method work in this case? Sometimes it just keep home and away and sometime it turn opposite home and away..can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: @betdavid1 - It sorting values alphanumeric per rows, more info is [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)

Comment: One more question, if I have for example 7 matches of Team 1 vs Team 2 and I want to calculate mean just of first six (without the last one). Where should I add that [:-1]? Thanks

Comment: @betdavid1 - added to new question.