# Mean of the certain rows of columns

Tags: python, pandas, mean

Update:
Original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908161/faster-way-to-get-mean-of-columns): I need to get mean of total goals from H2H matches.
Input:

```
Home   Away   Home_goals Away_goals 
------------------------------------
Team 1 Team 2 2          1          
Team 3 Team 4 3          5
Team 2 Team 1 5          3
Team 4 Team 3 1          5
```

Output:

```
Home   Away   Home_goals Away_goals Mean
------------------------------------------------------
Team 1 Team 2 2          1          5.5 ((2+1+5+3)/2) 
Team 3 Team 4 3          5          7 ((3+5+1+5)/2)
Team 2 Team 1 5          3          5.5 ((2+1+5+3)/2) 
Team 4 Team 3 1          5          7 ((3+5+1+5)/2)
```

Code below work fine but I came across another question. What if I have n matches between team 1 and team 2 and I want to calculate mean based on n-1 matches (without the last one). Can I just somehow change the code below?

```
a = np.sort(df[["Home", "Away"]], axis=1)
df['Mean'] = (pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index)
                .assign(sum = df[['Home_goals','Away_goals']].sum(axis=1))
                .groupby([0,1])['sum']
                .transform('mean'))
```

Thanks

Comment: First, could you please phrase the question in a way that allows one to easily reproduce the challenge you're facing? Second, is it always 6 out of 7? Always ignore the last one? Some other logic?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `iloc` to lambda function in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
a = np.sort(df[["Home", "Away"]], axis=1)
df['Mean'] = (pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index)
                .assign(sum = df[['Home_goals','Away_goals']].sum(axis=1))
                .groupby([0,1])['sum']
                .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].mean()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following produces a mean for every two-team combination while dropping the last game.

I added a couple of games to demonstrate that:

```
Home   Away   Home_goals Away_goals 
Team-1 Team-2 2          1          
Team-3 Team-4 3          5
Team-2 Team-1 5          3
Team-4 Team-3 1          5
Team-2 Team-1 10        10
Team-4 Team-3 10        10
```

Code:

```
a = np.sort(df[["Home", "Away"]], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["team1", "team2"])], axis="columns")
df["sum"] = df[["Home_goals", "Away_goals"]].sum(axis="columns")

drop_last = df.groupby(["team1", "team2"]).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1]).drop(["team1", "team2"], axis="columns").reset_index()
drop_last["mean"] = drop_last.groupby(["team1", "team2"])["sum"].transform("mean")
drop_last = drop_last[["team1", "team2", "mean"]]
drop_last = drop_last.drop_duplicates()

res = pd.merge(df, drop_last, on = ["team1", "team2"])
print(res)
```

result:

```
     Home    Away  Home_goals  Away_goals   team1   team2  sum  mean
0  Team-1  Team-2           2           1  Team-1  Team-2    3   5.5
1  Team-2  Team-1           5           3  Team-1  Team-2    8   5.5
2  Team-2  Team-1          10          10  Team-1  Team-2   20   5.5
3  Team-3  Team-4           3           5  Team-3  Team-4    8   7.0
4  Team-4  Team-3           1           5  Team-3  Team-4    6   7.0
5  Team-4  Team-3          10          10  Team-3  Team-4   20   7.0
```

Comment: But if this drop the last game, which is the second game in this case, than the mean should be calculated just from the first game - so for team 1 vs team 2 it should be 1.5 and for other teams 4

Comment: @betdavid1 - true. I accidentally didn't include the data I used, which contains a third game. See the modified post.